# Show the time in list view of Google Inbox

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Is there a way to see the date/time stamp of emails in Google Inbox's list view? It seems like a logical thing to want to see, so either:

- It's there and I haven't noticed it
- It somehow goes against the Inbox UI interaction model

Comment: I don't think it's there. At least I haven't found it either (if you don't open the mail, as I believe @Vembu is referring to in his answer).

Comment: I also think like you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

The answer would appear to be **no**.

The information in list of conversations is very spare. The subject is the most important thing, followed by the (partial) list of participants in the conversation. Then are the various action icons. I suppose I can see why they wouldn't want to put the date/time there; it probably shouldn't much matter when the latest message arrived, if you already know you want to dismiss it, snooze it, or pin it. If you don't know what you want to do you're going to have to open it anyway. Further, if you're *really* into Inbox, you're probably working on "Inbox Zero" regularly anyway, so the message can't be that old and they're listed in descending date order anyway. (This is just me speculating as to what the designers are thinking about your experience.)

If you want to see timestamps I'm afraid you have to click on the conversation to see the individual messages (even if there is only one message in the conversation).

Answer (score 1):

Not at all the solution, but this helps me:

In the "search" field at the top of the Inbox window, simply enter an "*".

Then the window will populate with all email AND show the DATE as a field (right-most field in the display).

Comment: this shows time for emails whose date is today. It shows date and not time for other emails.